# Load JSON data into table view using Xcode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to load a data from a JSON file. I've added this file to my Project Files in Xcode 4.6, but every time I run my code, I get empty cells in the TableView, with no data at all, even though I've declared a properly for each label and assigned a value for them from the JSON file.

I have created two classes: `events.h` and `.m`, `jsonloader.h` and `.m`, and imported them into my main view controller.

Here's a sample of my JSON data:

```
{
"Events": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "parr jazz presents zoe chiotis",
        "performingArtists": "Zoe Chiotis",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "date": "2013-12-03",
        "lastUpdated": "2013-12-03",
        "startingTime": "8:00:00 PM",
        "endingTime": "1:00:00 AM",
        "venue": "STUDIO2",
        "location": {
            "streetAddress": "33-45 Parr Street",
            "postCode": "L1 4JN"
        },
        "music genre": "Jazz",
        "information": "ZOE CHIOTIS is a singer/songwriter/guitarist based in Manchester. ",
        "image": "http://bandonthewall.org/images/content/large/zoe-chiotis-1764.jpg",
        "thumb": "http://swingbands.co.uk/wp-content/zoechiotis.jpg"
    },
...

]}
```

This is `event.m`:

```
@implementation JSONLoader

- (NSArray *)eventsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "Events"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Events"];
    // Iterate through the array of dictionaries
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        // Create a new event object for each one and initialise it with information in the dictionary
        Events *dataevents = [[Events alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
        // Add the Location object to the array
        [events addObject:dataevents];
    }

    // Return the array of Location objects
    return events;
}
```

and in my `mainViewController.m` I included this:

```
@implementation MV_HomeViewController {
    NSArray *_events;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
    JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"EventsData" withExtension:@"json"];

    // Load the data on a background queue...
    // As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _events = [jsonLoader eventsFromJSONFile:url];
        // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
        [self.myTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });       
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_events count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    MV_CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MV_CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    //[[cell textLabel] setText:_eventType];
    Events *event = [_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = event.title;
    cell.GenreLabel.text = event.musicGenre;

    return cell;

}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is here?

Comment: Three questions: in your Controller h file you did put the <uitableviewdelegate> As your promise to implement the Protocol? Second: you did tell your table that your Controller wants to be the delegate? Third: did you use NSLog to find out if your tableview Delegate methods are called at all?

Comment: You should log events.count in numberOfRowsInSection to see if it's returning something other than 0 (and if it gets logged at all). It should log 0 immediately, and then something >0 after the dispatch_async method returns.

Comment: @DerWOK Answering ur questions, yes for the first one i did that, for the second one Im not really sure what do u mean by that (Im quiet new to Objective-C and Xcode), for ur third question i did not include NSLog as it is clear from my above code, where do u suggest I should include it ??

Comment: @rdelmar isn't that what i did ??

Comment: @rdelmar - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_events count];
  }

Comment: I asked you to put a log in numberOfRowsInSection to see what it returns, you haven't done that.  Also, did you set the controller as the data source for the table (you should probably set the delegate as well, but that's not important for the code you show -- all those methods are data source methods).

Comment: @rdelmar I added this line to numberOfRawsInsection --> NSLog(@"Loading Data");

Comment: @rdelmar and i didn't get any this message back when i ran the code !!

Comment: Then you probably didn't set the controller as the data source of the table. In viewDidLoad, put this: self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

Comment: @rdelmar I can not thank u enough .. it works now, Im very happy :D Can I ask another question?? if I have two buttons in my main view controller one for displaying todays events and the other for displaying future events ?? what is the best way to do that ??

Comment: You have to filter your JSON data based on the value of the "date" key. One button's method would filter the data, so only dictionaries with today's date would be added to _events, and the other, only dictionaries with a date later than today.

Comment: @rdelmar how could I code if the date (key) is equal to todays date in Xcode ?? I mean how would the app knows about today's date and any future dates ??

Comment: [NSDate date] returns the current time and date. You probably want to read up on the NSDate, NSDateComponents, and NSCalendar classes. If you want to check if a particular date (which includes the time) is today, you would need to check the date components for month, day, and year to see that they're all the same. The value for your "date" key is probably a string though, so you'll have to convert it to an NSDate object first (so read up on NSDateFormatter as well).

Comment: @rdelmar do u mind taking a look on my second question that I have posted two hours ago, it is regarding the same issue we discussed above and the user who answered that question did not really clarify enough for me so it would be very helpful if u take a look at it and tell me what is going wrong !! .. thank u